Modelica.Media.R134a setState
I'm currently modeling an ejector expansion device as part of a refrigeration cycle and am facing a challenge with calculating the pressure at the outlet of the diffuser, referred to as _6
. At this point in the system, I have the specific enthalpy (ℎ_6) and entropy (_6), and I need to determine the pressure. However, the R134a library in Modelica does not seem to include a function like setState_hs for directly setting the state based on specific enthalpy and entropy.
I am looking for advice on how to resolve this issue. If anyone has suggestions on alternative methods to calculate the pressure from h_6 and S_6 or how to possibly implement a custom solution within the Modelica framework, I would greatly appreciate your insights.
Thank you!

H,S inputs are an uncommon pair for equations of state, so it will likely need to be solved by iteration. If you have access to a PH state, you could iteratively guess pressure along with the known enthalpy until the reaulting entropy matches your desired value. Modelica can do this for you if you use code like the pseudocode below.
s_target is the desired entropy
h is the known enthalpy
p_guess is the pressure required to compute properties using a PH EOS method.
state.setState_pH(p=p_guess, h)
s_target = state.s
Hopefully this helps.

There are multiple options, but the problem is that it is numerically sensitive. I copied one of the example models of MSL and tried to compute the state given a slightly different entropy as follows:
model R134a1 "Example 1 for R134a"
  extends Modelica.Icons.Example;
  extends Modelica.Media.Examples.Utilities.PartialTestModel(
    redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.R134a.R134a_ph,
    h_start=107390,
    fixedMassFlowRate(use_T_ambient=false),
    volume(use_T_start=false),
    ambient(use_T_ambient=false));
    Modelica.Media.R134a.R134a_ph.BaseProperties base;
    Real s1,s2;
    parameter Real sdiff=1e-1;
equation 
    base.h=volume.medium.h;
    s2=Modelica.Media.R134a.R134a_ph.specificEntropy(volume.medium.state);
    s1=Modelica.Media.R134a.R134a_ph.specificEntropy(base.state);
    s1=s2+sdiff;
  annotation (experiment(StopTime=1.01), uses(Modelica(version="4.0.0")));
end R134a1;

For sdiff of 0.1 that means the pressure changes from 1.1 to 0.81 bar; and larger differences seem to give weird results.
The key part of computing the properties based on h and s is the following:
    Modelica.Media.R134a.R134a_ph.BaseProperties base;
    Real s1;
equation 
    base.h=...;
    s1=Modelica.Media.R134a.R134a_ph.specificEntropy(base.state);
    s1=...;


Thank you for your help. What you provided has helped me take a step forward in my work. I have a question concerning the need for temperature, volume, and mass flow rate. Is it necessary to provide these parameters? I don't need them in my model.
